# Get specific message from output and store info to a log file

Tags: bash, logging, expect

I have a telnet expect script only used for check if the server is ok.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set IP 192.168.5.100
catch {spawn -noecho telnet $IP}
set timeout 3
expect {
  timeout
    { send_user "Telnet timed out waiting for $IP\n" ; exit }
  "onnection refused"
    { send_user "Connection was refused to $IP\n" ; exit }
  "No route"
    { send_user "System $IP is unknown\n" ; exit}
  "login:"
}
send_user "Success\n" ; exit
```

THis is working perfect and I call it from anothe bash script to store the message into a log file. The problem is that the output have too many information, e.g. in case the server is not reachable:

```
# ./checkconn.expect                 
Trying 192.168.5.101...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.5.101: No route to host
System 192.168.5.101 is unknown
```

In case the server is reachable:

```
Trying 192.168.5.100...
Connected to 192.168.5.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
--- Unauthorised access prohibited ---
This is a closed-access system. If you do not have permission
to access this system, then log off now. If you remain logged on
you consent to monitoring of your actions.
z1 login: Success
```

So I would like to store into log ONLY the message sent by expect script, like in the above example "System 192.168.5.101 is unknown"

How can I do this?
Thank you
Lucas

Comment: Can pipe the output into a filter (e.g. `sed`) and redirect it to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expect` utility has proc named `log_file` to record the logs.

In `man expect`:

```
log_file [args] [[-a] file]
             If  a filename is provided, log_file will record a transcript of the session (beginning at that point) in the file.  log_file will stop recording if no argument is given.  Any previous log file is
             closed.

         Instead of a filename, a Tcl file identifier may be provided by using the -open or -leaveopen flags.  This is similar to the spawn command.  (See spawn for more info.)

         The -a flag forces output to be logged that was suppressed by the log_user command.

         By default, the log_file command appends to old files rather than truncating them, for the convenience of being able to turn logging off and on multiple times in one session.  To  truncate  files,
         use the -noappend flag.

         The -info flag causes log_file to return a description of the most recent non-info arguments given.`
```

You can just use like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set IP 192.168.5.100
catch {spawn -noecho telnet $IP}
set timeout 3
log_file your_log_file.log
---
---
---
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will log everything not only the "send_user" message.

Comment: @LucasRey: can you try capturing only the output of `send_user` by redirecting it's output to a log file, something like this: `{ send_user "System $IP is unknown\n"  >> /path_to_log_file ; exit}`  .

Comment: No, it doesn't work, but if I add "log_user 0" it disable everything except the send_user message who will be redirect to a log file, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your script is executed by entering

```
./yourscript
```

then you can use something like the following pipe:

```
./yourscript | sed -n '/^System.*is unknown$/p' > logfile
```

Comment: Thnak you, but I would like to store every message sent by expect script, not only the one I provided as example.